# Showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p, \sqrt[p]{\ell}) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell})$ for $p,\ell$ primes.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

We consider the polynomial $x^p - \ell$, where $p,\ell$ are both prime numbers. Let $\zeta_p$ be a $p$-th root of unity. We wish to show that $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p, \sqrt[p]{\ell})$ is the same as $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell})$. Here are some of the facts I have already proved:

- The polymial $x^p - \ell$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
- $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) : \mathbb{Q}] = p-1$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{\ell}):\mathbb{Q}] = p$.
- $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{\ell})$ is the splitting field of $x^p - \ell$ and has degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{\ell}) : \mathbb{Q}] = p(p-1) = p^2 - p$. Furthermore, $L$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

My first attempt was to show both inclusions. One is trivial, but the other one is much, much harder, i.e. showing $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{\ell}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell})$. I thought expanding $(\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell})^p$ with the binomial expansion would be useful, but it turns out to be uglier than I expected.

I further notice that one way to reduce the problem is to show that the only automorphism $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ that fixes $\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell}$ is the identity map $1$, so that $L$ and $K$ must coincide. Since $\sigma(\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell}) = \sigma(\zeta_p) + \sigma(\sqrt[p]{\ell})$ and $\sigma$ only permutes the roots, we see  that $\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell} \mapsto \zeta_p^m + \zeta_p^n\sqrt[p]{\ell}$ under $\sigma$ for some $m,n \in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$. Hence, it suffices to show that
$$\zeta_p + \sqrt[p]{\ell} = \zeta_p^m + \zeta_p^n\sqrt[p]{\ell} \iff (m,n) = (1,0)$$
to conclude. However, I don't know where to go from there.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated. If there is an easier to show this, please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were very near to the full solution. If $n\neq 0$, you can rewrite your equality as

$$
\sqrt[p]{\ell}=\frac{\zeta_p-\zeta_p^m}{1-\zeta_p^n}
$$

So you deduce $\sqrt[p]{\ell} \in {\mathbb Q}(\zeta_p)$, and it is very easy to finish from there.

Comment: A very transparent approach to get the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Take a real positive choice for $\sqrt[p]{\ell}$, and for $\zeta$ take $\exp(2i\pi /p)$.  The sum $\zeta +\sqrt[p]\ell$ will be closer to real axis whereas $\zeta^m +\zeta^n\sqrt[p]\ell$ may be far away from real axis (easy to visualize for $\ell\gg p$.)

Comment: Rearrange your equation and get $\zeta-\zeta^m= \sqrt[p]{\ell}(\zeta^n-1)$. From this you can get an expression for $\sqrt[p]\ell$ and it can be checked to be of modulus 1 (being a unit in cyclotomic integers) giving a contradiction.

Comment: This is not correct. Take $p=7$ and $\ell=2$ with $\zeta=2^{2\pi i/7}$. Then $\zeta^{\color{Red}3}+\sqrt[7]{2}$ is closer to the real axis than $\zeta+\sqrt[7]{2}$ is. In reply to your comment, $-\zeta\frac{1-\zeta^{m-1}}{1-\zeta^n}$ will not generally have absolute value $1$. (Only if $m-1\equiv n$ mod $p$.) Since $(1-\zeta^n)$ is a prime (lying above $p$) in ${\cal O}_{\Bbb Q(\zeta)}=\Bbb Z[\zeta]$, the element $1-\zeta^n$ is not a unit in the cyclotomic integers. Ewan has the correct version of the argument you're looking for.

Comment: @ sea turtles: $\frac{1-\zeta^a}{1-\zeta^b}$ is a unit for $a,b <p$, so when multiplied by $-\zeta$ the product is also a unit. I do not understand your objection.

Comment: Oh you're right, since $1-\zeta^a$ and $1-\zeta^b$ generate the same prime ideal they are associate, so their ratio is a unit. Are you going to address the rest of my comment?

Comment: @sea turtles: My answer in the outline compares modulus of rhs with that of lhs and shows they are different. The main answer approaches to show their argument as complex numbers will be different. I'll work it out carefully.

Comment: How does your answer show that $-\zeta\frac{1-\zeta^{m-1}}{1-\zeta^n}$ and $\sqrt[p]{\ell}$ have different absolute value? Your comment incorrectly says the first has modulus $1$. Note that being a unit isn't the same as having absolute value $1$. I don't see any answer here that talks about their argument as complex numbers, either.

Comment: $\ell$ being a positive prime number is greater than 1.

Comment: Yes. My question is how you show they have different modulus.

Comment: Ok, I understand what I goofed up. Being a unit never implies being of absolute value 1. However being a unit means it lies in that cyclotomic field and so is  an algebraic number of degree $p-1$ or less. Whereas $\sqrt[p]\ell$ is an algebraic number of   degree $p$. Thanks sea turtles for being persistent and making me realize my sloppiness and finally making me arrive at the correct argument. My first approach about one number being closer to real axis than the other  means its argument is smaller than that of the other. I'll work it out.

Comment: No problem. ${}$

Comment: It is not the absolute value, it should be the norm of the algebraic number that will be different for a unit ($\pm 1$) and a non-unit. To avoid questions about which norm function $N_{F/Q}$,  take as definition of norm the constant term of the minimal polynomial over the rationals.

Comment: Right. Although to continue that form of argument one would then have to argue $\sqrt[p]{\ell}$ is not a unit or has different norm (which isn't difficult at all: do it from $L$ to $\Bbb Q$).

Answer (score 0):

If $L=F(\theta)$ and $f(\theta)$ is a polynomial in $\theta$ of lesser degree than $ [L:F]$, then $f(\theta)\ne0$. Corollary: $f(\theta)=g(\theta)$ as values in $L$ implies $f(x)=g(x)$ as polynomials in $F[x]$ if $\deg f,\deg g< [L:F]$.

Consider applying this knowledge to $F=\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ and $\theta=\sqrt[p]{\ell}$.

While this isn't as elegant as Ewan's answer, I think the above is an important, natural and intuitive fact to have in one's arsenal when thinking about elements in an extension field given in a power basis.